# Text appears after hitting the return key in a UITextField

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios4, xcode4

I have a custom class to create a textview with lines like the Notes app from Apple.

This is how the class looks:

NoteView.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface NoteView : UITextView <UITextViewDelegate> {
}


@end
```

NoteView.m

```
#import "NoteView.h"

@implementation NoteView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:0.6f alpha:1.0f];
        self.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:20];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    //Get the current drawing context   
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); 
    //Set the line color and width
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.2f].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);
    //Start a new Path
    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    //Find the number of lines in our textView + add a bit more height to draw lines in the empty part of the view
    NSUInteger numberOfLines = (self.contentSize.height + self.bounds.size.height) / self.font.leading;

    //Set the line offset from the baseline.
    CGFloat baselineOffset = 6.0f;

    //Iterate over numberOfLines and draw each line
    for (int x = 0; x < numberOfLines; x++) {
        //0.5f offset lines up line with pixel boundary
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, self.bounds.origin.x, self.font.leading*x + 0.5f + baselineOffset);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, self.bounds.size.width, self.font.leading*x + 0.5f + baselineOffset);
    }

    //Close our Path and Stroke (draw) it
    CGContextClosePath(context);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}

@end
```

I add the view as a subview. Everything works fine, but the text only apears after I hit the return key. I can see the flashing cursor, when I type I can see the cursor moving, but the text is gone... After hitting the return key, the text becomes visible and after that everything works fine. Even when I select all the text, remove it and start typing the text is visible.

This is how the textarea looks like:

[image]

How to solve this?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

This is how I alloc the view:

```
annotateText = [[NoteView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85.0, 168.0, 600.0, 567.0)];
    annotateText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [annotateText setText:[annotationNotes objectAtIndex:0]];

    [paperAnnotationView addSubview:annotateText];
```

Comment: Did you try to set the text color explicitly?

Comment: First check you have your delegate set up correctly. Then try it without overriding drawRect (in case this is conflicting somehow). Then maybe post code showing where/how you alloc/init your NoteView. Oh, and show us your shouldChangeCharactersInRange method.

Comment: Well I need to override the drawRect to create the lines like in the picture I've added. Otherwise the text doesn't get aligned perfectly on the lines... Or do you have a better idea?

Comment: Also tried setting the text color, no difference...

Comment: Were you able to solve it yet? I haven't been able to find a solution. Seems to be a bug from Apple's side.

Comment: I have successfully implemented without any problem please check out this tutorial http://geekios.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/make-the-note-view-using-uitextfield/

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old. I ran into the same issue and was looking for a solution. So I thought I would post the answer here, just in case, if any one comes and looks for it. After pulling my hair for hours, I figured out that the text view wont display the text in the very first line (unless we press enter/return or scroll the text) when the bounds of the textview is off the screen. Even when the parent view is off the screen, I ran into the same issue.

Here is the code that I was working on.

```
    self.captionView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(231, 769, 563, 643)] autorelease];  //63
    self.captionView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ekp006_preview_fbsharecontainer"];
    self.captionView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    //self.captionView.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"ekp006_preview_fbsharecontainer"].CGImage;

    UIButton *cancelButton = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 73, 34)] autorelease];
    [cancelButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ekp006_preview_fbshare_btn_cancel"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cancelButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ekp006_preview_fbshare_btn_cancel_down"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelFacebookShare) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.captionView addSubview:cancelButton];

    UIButton *shareButton = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(480, 10, 73, 34)] autorelease];
    [shareButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ekp006_preview_fbshare_btn_share"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [shareButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ekp006_preview_fbshare_btn_share_down"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(facebookshare) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.captionView addSubview:shareButton];

    self.captionTextView = [[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 60, 523, 100)] autorelease];
    self.captionTextView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.captionTextView.delegate = self;
    self.captionTextView.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0;
    self.captionTextView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.captionTextView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
    self.captionTextView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.captionTextView.layer.borderWidth = 0.75;
    self.captionTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    self.captionTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"VAGRoundedBlackSSi" size:18];
    [self.captionView addSubview:self.captionTextView];

    [[self topMostViewController].view addSubview:self.captionView];
```

If you see closely, the parent view for me (the caption view) was 769 in y origin and I made this explicit, so that I can make the view slide from bottom to top using UIView animations. In order to solve this, I had to take the alternate path of making the parent view frame as CGRectMake(231,63,563,643) and hide the entire view. And to present it I used something like this.

```
- (void) presentCaptionCaptureScreen
{
    // The code which works
    [AnimationEffects bounceAnimationForView:self.captionView afterTimeInterval:0];
    self.captionTextView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.captionTextView.text = @"Enter your caption for the photo";

    // The code which didn't work
/*
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^
    {
        self.captionTextView.text = @"";
        self.captionView.frame = CGRectMake(231, 63, 563, 643);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
    {
        self.captionTextView.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        self.captionTextView.text = @"Enter your caption for the photo";
    }];
     */
}
```

It worked for me!